# Escaped html is again unescaped in jquery html method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-escape-characters

I want to escape a title text in a div. But when feeding the escaped text into html() call, its again un-escaping it. Here is the code

```
const title = $('<div/>').text('test <script>').html(); // test &amp;lt;script&amp;gt;
const span = `<span title="${title}">Hello world</span>`; // still correct
$('#test').html(span);
```

but now the generated html inside #span has again 'test <script';
check the demo here:

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", () => {
  const title = $('<div/>').text('test <script>').html();
  const span = `<span title="${title}">Hello world</span>`;
  $('#test').html(span);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p id="test">Hello World</p>
  <button>Add title</button>
</div>
```

1. Click the button add title
2. Hover the element to check the title

Expected: Show title as "test &lt;script&gt;"

Actual: Showing title as "test "

Comment: what is exactly the output that you are trying to produce?

Comment: want the title as: "test &amp;lt;script&amp;gt;"

Comment: It is working fine in chrome..in which browser are you trying it?

Comment: Tried in chrome and FF, I want to show text "test &amp;lt;script&amp;gt;" when hovering, currently its showing "test <script>"

Answer (score 1):

Escape the string a second time.

```js
function escape_html(str) {
    return str.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') ;
}

// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", () => {
  let title = escape_html(escape_html('test <script>'));
  const span = `<span title="${title}">Hello world</span>`;
  $('#test').html(span);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p id="test">Hello World</p>
  <button>Add title</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This code will FAIL if the tag to show is `</script>` unless the script is external to the page

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot break the script tag, you can escape the tag on the server or in a tag

Note the code here is abusing a deprecated `xmp` tag to show the issue because
you **CANNOT** have `</script>` anywhere in your script unless the script is external to the page - so if you plan to show

```
<script>alert('Hello')</script>
```

then the page will not load correctly if the above string is not in xmp tags

I have given TWO solutions based on original question and subsequent comment

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  const $converter = $("<div/>").text($("#textFromServer").text())

  // Expected: Show title as "test &lt;script&gt;"

  $("#test1").prop("title", $converter.html())

  // want the title as: "test &amp;lt;script&amp;gt;" 

  $("#test2").prop("title", $converter.html().replace(/&/g, "&amp;"))
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="banner-message">
  <p id="test1">Hello World</p>
  <p id="test2">Hello World</p>
  <button>Add title</button>
</div>

<xmp style="display:none" id="textFromServer">test <script></xmp>
```